# mailR Connection refused from linux but not from windows

Tags: java, linux, r

I have mailR (the R language package to send email) try to send some emails from my gmail account.
It works flawlessly from windows, but from linux I get the errors below.
In the example below I have replaced emails, usernames and passwords.

Code:

```
library(mailR)
emails <- c("example1@host.com")

send.emails <- function() {
  for(x in emails){
    send.mail(from = from1,
    to = x,
    subject = subject1,
    body = body1,
    smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = username,
    passwd = password, ssl = TRUE),
    authenticate = TRUE,
    send = TRUE)
  }
}

send.emails()
```

Errors:

```
> send.emails()
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.NULL
java:606)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1984)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:299)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:208)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1950)
    ... 13 more
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Again, I get no error at all on windows and the emails go through, when I run the same script on linux, i get all those errors. Connection refused...

If I could run this script from my linux box that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The error is that it can't connect to `smtp.gmail.com` on port 465. Have you verified the linux firewall isn't blocking the traffic? Have you tested whether you can `ping smtp.gmail.com` from a terminal prompt, and have you verified port connectivity via `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 -crlf`? This really isn't an R or apache question, too.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit the question. I was just so used to R having portability problems between platforms I didn't realize peer guardian might be blocking the smtp server, especially since it doesn't noticeably block any other google servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have an answer. Suprisingly, it's not a problem with R working on windows and not on linux (like download.file --internet2 or many other examples).

Peerguardian is running on the linux system and somehow smtp.gmail.com is on a blacklist.

I've whitelisted smtp.gmail.com and now everything works!

I was able to whitelist by IP or whitelist port 465, either worked.